# The meaning of "showing place"

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does "showing place" mean in the following explanation for "serial number"? I don't think it means something should be made aware of its low status. Thank you!

"[Serial number : a number showing place in a series and used as a means of identification](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serial%20number#:%7E:text=Kids%20Definition-,serial%20number,Jan%202024%20%2D%20Updated%20example%20sentences)"

Comment: It's (slightly) awkward phrasing equivalent to *... **means**  a number **which shows the position** in a series and **is** used as a means of identification*. So if you have 100 books, you could in theory arrange them in some sequence (alphabetical by title, by date of publication, whatever), then refer to each book by its "Serial Number" - an "element number / subscript" into that series of numbers 1-100. It's obviously nothing to do with one's metaphorical "place / position" within the social ["pecking order".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pecking%20order)

Comment: Your parse is incorrect: **place in a series**

Comment: The number **shows** the **place** of the item in a series - that is, whether it's first, second or 99th. Nothing to do with status.

Comment: Wow.  Bad sentence twice over.  Your confusion is well justified. "showing place" would be better as "showing the place".  But Serial Number is an identifier more than a "place" in a series.  Serial Numbers are closer to ledger entries.  For example, given a Serial Number a manufacturer can locate all components of the manufactured item, the date it was manufactured, and if it has any safety recalls.  Serial Number is bigger than a "place in a series"

Answer (score 1):

"Showing place" is not a two-word phrase here; that is, it's just a meaning for "show" and a meaning for "place" that you're looking for. It's complicated by a few funny usages: first of all, "showing" can be read as "that shows." It's using an infinitive to talk about a property, like "a conifer is a tree *producing* cones." Also, we're not really looking at a full sentence here; there's no main verb. Definitions are often written this way.

A rewrite that might make the meaning clearer would be:

> A serial number is a number that shows something's place in a series and that is used as a means of identification.